# What is the significance of an array at the end of an __init__.py file?

Tags: python, package, init

I am reading code for a package file (edit: a custom package in a shared repository) with a structure similar to this:

```
# some_package/__init__.py

from foo import a1
from bar import b1, b2

[
    a1,
    b1,
    b2
]
```

That is the extent of the file.

Is this array an implicit declaration of the `__all__` method?

Comment: Which package? Just wondering

Comment: It's a custom package in a shared repository. It seems to be an implicit design standard for the repo, but I'm not sure what its significance is.

Comment: It has no significance — at least it doesn't do anything noticeable/significant except waste a few cycles.

Comment: My wild guess: The IDE complained that the imports were not used.

Comment: This is not doing anything. I think it might be a mistake. Even if they put \__all__ = ['a1','b1','b2'] it would not be usefull

Answer (score 0):

It is not there for any good reason. Without being a declared variable, it does nothing but waste time. It could be there to delay everything microscopically, but probably not as this could be done in other ways.